# jQuery animating to a new div

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of divs setup.

```
<div class="terrain water"></div>

<div class="terrain water"></div>

<div class="terrain water"></div>

<div class="terrain water"></div>
```

Every div represent a "tile" in width: 32px height: 32px. I also have a character div who places inside the the tile div.

```
<div class="terrain water"><div class="character"></div></div>
```

When I want to move the character div to another div, I would also want to animate. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not clear at all. Please be more clear.

Comment: WHAT do you want to animate? Movement? Fade it in/out? Both? Want it to do a backflip?

Comment: I want to animate some sort of a movement.

Comment: how do you move the character div to another div?

Comment: I am using http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate your character div's opacity to 0 first, move it, then animate it back to 1 after you append it to your other div. That will give a disappeared appeared effect.

```
$(".character").animate({"opacity":0}, 1000).appendTo("Your other div").animate({"opacity":1},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can animate the character with fade effect.

```
$(".character").fadeOut().appendTo("Your other div").fadeIn();
```